# Scandinavian letters in email form

Tags: php

I am having trouble getting the scandinavian letters ÆØÅ/æøå to work in my email form. The form sends the message and I recieve it just fine, except when there is ÆØÅ/æøå in the message.

Any help is highly appreciated!

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
$header = "Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n";

session_start();
ob_start();
$dontsendemail = 0;
$possiblespam = FALSE;
$strlenmessage = "";
$email = $_POST['email']; 
$message = $_POST['message'];
$subject = $_POST['subject'];


$emailaddress = array();
$emailaddress[1] = "lalala@lalala.lala";
    $emailaddress[2] = "lalala@llllaaa.laaaa";
    $emailaddress[3] = "laaaverksted@laa.verksted";
    $emailaddress[4] = "ess@xfrag.com";
    $contactnameindex = $_POST['emailaddress'];
if ($contactnameindex == 0 || !isset($_POST['emailaddress'])) echo '<div id="notification" class="info_div"><span class="ico_cancel">Du valgte ikke en mottaker.</span></div>';
else $emailaddress = $emailaddress[$contactnameindex];
function checkcaptcha() {
        if ($_SESSION["pass"] != $_POST["userpass"]) {
            echo '<div id="notification" class="info_div"><span class="ico_cancel">Beklager, men feilet i å skrive inn bildeverifiseringen. Merk at bildeverifiseringen krever at du skiller imellom store og små bokstaver.</span></div>';
            return 1;
        }
    }

function checkemail($field) {
// checks proper syntax
if( !preg_match( "/^([a-zA-Z0-9])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-])*@([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+)+$/", $field))
{
    echo '<div id="notification" class="info_div"><span class="ico_cancel">Feilaktig e-postadresse registrert.</span></div>'; 
    return 1;
}
}
function spamcheck($field) {
if(eregi("to:",$field) || eregi("cc:",$field) || eregi("\r",$field) || eregi("\n",$field) || eregi("%0A",$field)){ 
    $possiblespam = TRUE;
}else $possiblespam = FALSE;
if ($possiblespam) {
    echo '<div id="notification" class="info_div"><span class="ico_cancel">Mulig forsøk på spam oppdaget. Hvis dette ikke er tilfelle, kan du redigere innholdet i kontaktskjemaet, og prøv igjen.</span></div>';
    return 1;
}
}
function strlencheck($field,$minlength,$whichfieldresponse) {
if (strlen($field) < $minlength){
    die($whichfieldresponse); 
    return 1;
}
}

    if ($dontsendemail == 0) $dontsendemail = checkcaptcha($email);

if ($dontsendemail == 0) $dontsendemail = checkemail($email);
if ($dontsendemail == 0) $dontsendemail = spamcheck($email);
if ($dontsendemail == 0) $dontsendemail = spamcheck($subject);
if ($dontsendemail == 0) $dontsendemail = strlencheck($email,10,'<div id="notification" class="info_div"><span class="ico_cancel">E-mail feltet er for kort.</span></div>');

if ($dontsendemail == 0) $dontsendemail = strlencheck($subject,5,'<div id="notification" class="info_div"><span class="ico_cancel">Emnefeltet er for kort.</span></div>');

if ($dontsendemail == 0) $dontsendemail = strlencheck($message,10,'<div id="notification" class="info_div"><span class="ico_cancel">Meldingen er for kort.');
if ($dontsendemail == 0) $dontsendemail = strlencheck($emailaddress,8,'<div id="notification" class="info_div"><span class="ico_cancel">Du har ikke valgt en mottaker av meldingen.</span></div>');
if ($dontsendemail == 0){mail($emailaddress, "Emne: $subject","Fra: $email", $message); echo '<div id="sent" class="info_div"><span class="ico_success">Takk! Din e-post til oss er registrert og vil bli besvart innen 24-timer på dagene Mandag-Fredag.</span></div>'; }
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

Comment: @yes123 His code wouldn't work if he'd put all of those inside the same `if`.

Comment: Instead of telling him how awful his code looks (and yes, I must admit, I cried a little when I saw it myself) you might want to give constructive suggestions on how to make it look better instead of downvoting and generally being condescending.

Comment: I must say I agree with @Dennis here. Maybe take it down a notch or two.

Comment: @VHH, what happens when you use those characters in a message?

Comment: "Ã¦Ã¸Ã¥Ã†Ã˜Ã" - this is what it sends to me when using ÆØÅ and æøå. Thank you Dennis, I am fairly new to PHP coding. Would appreciate any help rewriting it as well. :-)

Comment: Of course didn't want to be arrogant. I just wanted to point out that the code could be more elegant

Answer (score 1):

Nowhere in your mail's body do you specify the character set of the content. The `header()` call you do at the top of the script does NOT apply to the email, it applies only to the output of the script sent to browser running this script.

Since it's an HTML email, you'd have to put a meta tag into the mail's `<head>` block:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

However, please don't build a MIME/html mail like this by hand. It's far too ugly. Use either [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org) or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) which do all the heavy work for you automatically. They're quick, easy, and free.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you forgot your browser encoding ? and also email-client encoding?

Additionally, you can't send an array to a mail(); function
EDIT: additionally, you should not use eregi(); as it's deprecated

Answer (score 0):

For historical reasons, the standard E-Mail encoding is ISO-8859-1.

To send your characters properly, you must either encode the E-mail explicitly as UTF-8 as shown here: [PHP Send UTF-8 mail without PEAR::Mail PEAR::Mail_Mime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500690/php-send-utf-8-mail-without-pearmail-pearmail-mime)

Alternatively, you could use `utf8_decode()` to turn the text into ISO-8859-1. That will, however, work only for western characters (= those covered by ISO-8859-1) - using UTF-8 all the way is the *much* better alternative.