# UTF-8 coding in mail contact form,

Tags: php, forms, email, character

I have a simple mailing script on my website but I don t know how to make the mail be sent with the right coding (using letters as "ľščťžýáíé" it ends with the mail containing wrong characters) Can anyone help me please? None of the solutions I found on the internet seemed to work (the mail wasn `t delivered at all)

The code :

```
    <?php
                 $error    = ''; 
                 $name     = ''; 
                 $email    = ''; 
                 $subject  = ''; 
                 $message  = ''; 

            if(isset($_POST['send']))
            {
                 $name     = $_POST['name'];
                 $email    = $_POST['email'];
                 $subject  = $_POST['subject'];
                 $message  = $_POST['message'];

                if(trim($name) == '')
                {
                    $error = '<div class="errormsg"><p>Zadajte prosím svoje meno.</p></div>';
                }
                    else if(trim($email) == '')
                {
                    $error = '<div class="errormsg"><p>Zadajte prosím svoju e-mailovú adresu.</p></div>';
                }
                else if(!isEmail($email))
                {
                    $error = '<div class="errormsg"><p>Zadajte prosím platnú e-mailovú adresu.</p></div>';
                }
                    if(trim($subject) == '')
                {
                    $error = '<div class="errormsg"><p>Zadajte prosím predmet správy.</p></div>';
                }
                else if(trim($message) == '')
                {
                    $error = '<div class="errormsg"><p>Napíšte prosím text správy.</p></div>';
                }

                if($error == '')
                {
                    if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                    {
                        $message = stripslashes($message);
                    }

                    $to      = "xyz@xyz.com";

                    $subject = '[Kontaktny formular xyzvlmedia.sk] : ' . $subject;

                    $msg     = "Odosielatel : $name \r\nE-mail : $email \r\nPredmet : $subject \r\n\n" . "Sprava : \r\n$message";

                    mail($to, $subject, $msg, "From: $email\r\nReply-To: $email\r\nReturn-Path: $email\r\n");
            ?>

                  <div class="thankyoumsg"><p>Ďakujeme <strong><?=$name;?></strong>! Vaša správa bola odoslaná.</p></div>

            <?php
                }
            }

            if(!isset($_POST['send']) || $error != '')
            {
            ?>

            <?=$error;?>

            <form method="post" name="contFrm" id="contFrm" action="">
<div class="formular">
                  Meno a priezvisko<br />
                  <input name="name" type="text" class="box" id="name" size="30" value="<?=$name;?>" /><br />
                  E-mail<br />
                  <input name="email" type="text" class="box" id="email" size="30" value="<?=$email;?>" /><br />
                  Predmet<br />
                  <input name="subject" type="text" class="box" id="subject" size="30" value="<?=$subject;?>" /><br />
                    Správa<br />
                  <textarea name="message" cols="40" rows="3"  id="message"><?=$message;?></textarea><br /><br />

                        <input name="send" type="submit" class="button" id="send" value="Odoslať" />
</div>
            </form>

            <?php
            }

            function isEmail($email)
            {
                return(preg_match("/^[-_.[:alnum:]]+@((([[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]][[:alnum:]-]*[[:alnum:]])\.)+(ad|ae|aero|af|ag|ai|al|am|an|ao|aq|ar|arpa|as|at|au|aw|az|ba|bb|bd|be|bf|bg|bh|bi|biz|bj|bm|bn|bo|br|bs|bt|bv|bw|by|bz|ca|cc|cd|cf|cg|ch|ci|ck|cl|cm|cn|co|com|coop|cr|cs|cu|cv|cx|cy|cz|de|dj|dk|dm|do|dz|ec|edu|ee|eg|eh|er|es|et|eu|fi|fj|fk|fm|fo|fr|ga|gb|gd|ge|gf|gh|gi|gl|gm|gn|gov|gp|gq|gr|gs|gt|gu|gw|gy|hk|hm|hn|hr|ht|hu|id|ie|il|in|info|int|io|iq|ir|is|it|jm|jo|jp|ke|kg|kh|ki|km|kn|kp|kr|kw|ky|kz|la|lb|lc|li|lk|lr|ls|lt|lu|lv|ly|ma|mc|md|mg|mh|mil|mk|ml|mm|mn|mo|mp|mq|mr|ms|mt|mu|museum|mv|mw|mx|my|mz|na|name|nc|ne|net|nf|ng|ni|nl|no|np|nr|nt|nu|nz|om|org|pa|pe|pf|pg|ph|pk|pl|pm|pn|pr|pro|ps|pt|pw|py|qa|re|ro|ru|rw|sa|sb|sc|sd|se|sg|sh|si|sj|sk|sl|sm|sn|so|sr|st|su|sv|sy|sz|tc|td|tf|tg|th|tj|tk|tm|tn|to|tp|tr|tt|tv|tw|tz|ua|ug|uk|um|us|uy|uz|va|vc|ve|vg|vi|vn|vu|wf|ws|ye|yt|yu|za|zm|zw)$|(([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5])\.){3}([0-9][0-9]?|[0-1][0-9][0-9]|[2][0-4][0-9]|[2][5][0-5]))$/i"
                        ,$email));
            }
            ?>

</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP Send UTF-8 mail without PEAR::Mail PEAR::Mail\_Mime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1500690/php-send-utf-8-mail-without-pearmail-pearmail-mime)

Comment: You don't check the return value of `mail`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the page with the form is sent with `header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");` and the meta tag

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Now add the appropriate mime type encoding to the mail header:

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n
```

Also check the return value of `mail()`:

```
$mail = mail(...);
if ($mail !== true) {
    // error sending mail
}
```

Comment: I'd use utf-8 rather than ISO-8859-1.

Comment: Please refresh your page

Answer (score 0):

Please look up how to send HTML emails through PHP. It's really easy, and it will solve your problem.

http://css-tricks.com/sending-nice-html-email-with-php/

```
$to = 'bob@example.com';
$subject = 'Website Change Reqest';

$headers = "From: " . strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n"; //obviously don't use strip_tags as this is not a safe way to escape your variables. Please do proper escaping and pass in a variable
$headers .= "Reply-To: ". strip_tags($_POST['req-email']) . "\r\n";
$headers .= "CC: susan@example.com\r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1>Hello, World!</h1>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
```

Make sure you include the header variable:

```
mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: `strip_tags` will not make your `POST` variable safe! This way you're vulnerable to mail header injection.

Answer (score 0):

This example solves your task:
 http://ekav.info/question-answer/index.php?qa=3&qa_1=how-to-set-charset-utf-8-in-e-mail-form

[see here](http://ekav.info/question-answer/index.php?qa=3&qa_1=how-to-set-charset-utf-8-in-e-mail-form)